# Classifying column in data.frame based on vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, classification

In the following data.frame `df` I would like to create a new column with values that will be derived from classification of `A` column. If number if `A` column corresponds to one of the numbers in `G1` vector, in new column called `Group` it should be classified as "G1". Similarly if value in `A` column corresponds to one of the values in `G2` vector, it should be classified as "G2". Remaining columns should be classified as "G0".

```
A <- seq(1900,2000,1)
B <- rnorm(101,10,2)
df <- data.frame(A=A,B=B)

G1 <- c(1963,1982,1952)
G2 <- c(1920,1933,1995)

# This doesn't do what I would like it to achieve
df$group <- ifelse(df$A == G1,"G1",ifelse(df$A == G2,"G2","G0"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking is

```
df$group <- ifelse(df$A %in% G1, "G1", ifelse(df$A %in% G2, "G2", "G0"))
```

which can be better represented with `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(group = case_when(A %in% G1 ~ "G1", 
                            A %in% G2 ~ "G2", 
                            TRUE ~ "G0"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't want to test whether a value in the column is *equal to* A or B; those are vectors and that test doesn't make sense. Instead, you want to know whether the value *is an element* of A or B. Tweak your code to

```
df$group <- ifelse(df$A %in% G1,"G1",ifelse(df$A %in% G2,"G2","G0"))
```

This worked when I checked it. There may be a more elegant solution, but this is closely aligned to your first attempt.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is what has been suggested by another person too, and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun and concise alternative:

```
df$group <- c("G0", "G1", "G2")[1 + 1 * df$A %in% G1 + 2 * df$A %in% G2]
```

---

We have a vector of three options `c("G0", "G1", "G2")`. Thinking element-wise, if none of `df$A %in% G1` and `df$A %in% G2` are true, we choose "G0" (due to `1 + ...` at the beginning). Since `G1` and `G2` don't overlap, "G1" will be chosen only if `df$A %in% G1`. Similarly, the index is 3 and "G2" is chosen only if `df$A %in% G2`.